# How to pivot on tough mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, pivot

I can do a pivot similar to the structure below, but i cant manage with Mongo.

Let'assume that we have a collection like this:

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("***"),
"date" : ISODate("2018-04-02T00:00:00Z"),
"parameters" : [
    { "name" : "value_1", "value" : 50 },
    { "name" : "value_2", "value" : 25 },
    { "name" : "value_3", "value" : 20 },
    { "name" : "value_4", "value" : 15 }
]},
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("***"),
"date" : ISODate("2018-04-15T00:00:00Z"),
"parameters" : [
    { "name" : "value_5", "value" : 10 },
    { "name" : "value_3", "value" : 20 },
    { "name" : "value_1", "value" : 10 },
    { "name" : "value_6", "value" : 25 }
]}
```

Now my intent is to pivot row to column in order to have something like this:

```
    {result :[
    {
        "name" : 'value1',
        "2018-04-02" : {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-04-02T00:00:00Z"),
            "value" : 50
        }
        "2018-04-15" : {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-04-15T00:00:00Z"),
            "value" : 10
        }
    },....
]}
```

This is tricky and tough at same time...

So I want to create an object to iterate with, to create a table where the rows are the name and its values over the time. and if in that date there is no value should be fill with a null value.

Maybe is not well designed, in this case please help me to project the collections...

thanks

**EDIT**

The output generated from @dnickless was awesome but hard to manage...
I tried to readapt the aggregation but is too complicated.

the output should be this:

```
  { "dates" : ["14-04-2018", "02-04-2018"],
  "result" : [
      {
          "parameters" : [50, 10],
          "name" : "value1"
      }, 
      {
          "parameters" : [25, null],
          "name" : "value2"
      }, 
      {
          "parameters" : [20, 20],
          "name" : "value3"
      }, 
      {
          "parameters" : [15, null],
          "name" : "value4"
      }....
  ]}
```

Can someone resolve this rubick cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pipeline.

Stage 1-7: Get all unique names and sort them.

Stage 8: For each document, fill missing values

Stage 11: Group documents by name.

Stage 12: Correct structure to match that of expect results.

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $project: {
      date: 1,
      parameters_: '$parameters',
      parameters: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$parameters'
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: {
        $addToSet: '$parameters.name'
      },
      parameterUndDate: {
        $addToSet: {
          parameters: '$$ROOT.parameters_',
          date: '$date'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$names'
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      names: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: {
        $push: '$names'
      },
      parameters_: {
        $first: '$$ROOT.parameterUndDate'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$parameters_'
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: '$parameters_.date',
      regularizedParameters: {
        $map: {
          input: '$names',
          as: 'needle',
          in: {
            $ifNull: [{
              $arrayElemAt: [{
                $filter: {
                      input: '$parameters_.parameters',
                  as: 'haystack',
                      cond: {
                        $eq: ['$$haystack.name', '$$needle']
                  }
                }
              },
                  0
              ]
            }, {
              name: '$$needle',
                value: null
            }]
          }
          }
        }
    }
  }
  {
    $unwind: '$regularizedParameters'
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$regularizedParameters.name',
      parameters: {
        $push: '$regularizedParameters.value'
      },
      dates: {
        $push: '$date'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      results: {
        $push: {
          parameters: '$parameters',
          name: '$_id'
        }
      },
      dates: {
        $first: '$dates'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
];


db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the below is probably one of the most horrific aggregation pipelines I have ever written (and almost certainly can be optimized by some smarter people like @veeram) it gets the job done for your very example from what I can tell...

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: { // this is to create an array "dates" that holds all date values
        _id: "$null",
        dates: { $push: "$date" },
        docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } // we remember all documents, so we can...
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs" // basically restore the original documents again after the grouping just with the new "dates" array that holds all date values
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs.parameters" // flatten the "parameters" array into individual documents
}, {
    $group: { // now group all documents into buckets
        _id: "$docs.parameters.name", // by the "name" field
        "dates": { $first: "$dates" }, // retain the globally identical "dates" array with all dates in it
        "docs": { $push: "$docs" } // remember all full documents per bucket
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "docs": {
            $arrayToObject: { // transform the key-value pairs created below into documents
                $map: { // loop through all dates
                    input: "$dates",
                    as: "this", // let the "$$this" variable point to the currently processed date
                    in: {
                        $let: { // this is to avoid duplicating the inner map stage which would otherwise be needed for the conditional handling below (see the "missing values" $cond bit)
                            vars: {
                                "arrayOrEmpty": { // create a variable "$$arrayOrEmpty" which will either hold a (single element) array or an empty array
                                    $map: { // loop again
                                        input: {
                                            $filter: { // locate the element in the (single element) "docs" array
                                                input: "$docs",
                                                as: "that", // let the "$$that" variable point to the currently processed document
                                                cond: { $eq: [ "$$that.date", "$$this" ] } // whose "date" field matches the date we're currently processing
                                            }
                                        },
                                        as: "that",
                                        in: {
                                            "k": { // we create a key-value pair that will...
                                                $dateToString : { // ...have a key like "2018-04-15" based on the date we're currently processing
                                                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                                                    date: "$$this"
                                                }               
                                            },
                                            "v": { // ...and a value that is a sub-document
                                                "date": "$$this", // ...with the full "date" inside 
                                                "value": "$$that.parameters.value" // ...and also the "value" field
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            in: { // this is to create a null entry for missing values
                                $cond: [
                                    { $ne: [ { $size: "$$arrayOrEmpty" }, 0 ] }, // check if empty array returned by previous $map magic
                                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arrayOrEmpty", 0 ] }, // if not then the first entry is what we want
                                    { // otherwise we create some dummy entry with a null value but the date fields set to what they should be set to...
                                        "k": {
                                            $dateToString : {
                                                format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                                                date: "$$this"
                                            }               
                                        },
                                        "v": {
                                            "date": "$$this",
                                            "value": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }          
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs" // flatten the "docs" array
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "docs.name": "$_id", // move the "_id" field into into the "docs" sub-document
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "docs.name": 1 // make sure the result is sorted by "name" (may or may not be needed)
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": null,
        "result": { $push: "$docs" } // this is just to create a "result" array as shown in your desired output
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0 // get rid of "_id" field
    }
})
```

As always with these pipelines, you can remove stages starting with the last one going all the way up in order to find out what on earth is going on here...

Comment: Thanks again @dnickless, you are a mongo god, but i found out that my pour design is hard to manage. can you extract a slightly different document?  separating dates and push values in an array? ps sorry for this request, but i am stuck.. 

{     
      "dates" : [ISODate("2018-04-02T00:00:00Z"), ISODate("2018-04-15T00:00:00Z")],
      "result" : [
          {
              "parameters" : [50, 10],
              "name" : "value1"
          }, 
          {
              "parameters" : [25, null],
              "name" : "value2"
          }, 
     ....
      ]
  }